# mobile view on bootstrap has extra white space at the bottom of container

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

[white space on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr0xO.png)

Top of the page has annoying whitespace that I am trying to figure out how to remove on mobile. I have tried different methods I have researched with nothing working. The container is class:content-intro-wrapper scoped Wondering the best method for reducing this space. Here is a link to the staging site for the page https://staging-digemaya.kinsta.cloud/the-life-changing-power-of-sophrology/

Thank you for your continued help as I navigate every changing issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main CSS file you have code like this:

```
@media (min-width: 400px)
{
    .content-intro-wrapper {
        min-height: 700px;
    }
}
```

use `min-height: auto` to remove space.

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Please select my answer as true answer. Thanks.